# php unless wordpress user role = "subscriber" display this html code

Tags: php, wordpress, roles

I need to display HTML code to all user roles except "subscriber" in wordpress.

Here is code that I can't get working.

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
?>

<?php if ( $current_user->role == 'subscriber' ) : ?>
    <span>here is my html</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

PS
I'm not that good with php as you can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I used following code that gives desired functionality:

```
<?php if ( $this->current_user_can_edit_posts ) : ?>
  <span>my html</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

For others, you might need to change "$this" part. So you can retrieve current_user. Maybe someone can still post an answer for them.

Comment: Oh I see you answered your own question. Great! Good code btw :)

Answer (score 0):

Tried and tested code that works. Let me know if it works for you too! :)

```
    <?php
      $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
      if ( ! in_array( 'subscriber', (array) $current_user->roles ) ) {
    ?>
      <span>here is my html</span>
    <?php
       } 
     ?>
```